# Grep-function: How to combine characters and a range of numbers

Tags: r, regex, numeric

I want to use the grep function in order to get specific items out of the data frame. All items of interest start with "ffcb2", but then I only want to select those ending with the numbers  07 to 16. Yet I don't know how to include this range correctly in the command. So far, it looks like this:

```
grep(names_data, pattern = "ffcb2[07-16]", value = TRUE)
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!

Comment: Of course, thanks for the hint! (I didn't know this function before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match numbers from `7` to `16` you may use a [numeric range regex generator](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/) to get the following pattern:

```
(0[7-9]|1[0-6])
```

So, your command will look like

```
grep(names_data, pattern = "ffcb2(0[7-9]|1[0-6])", value = TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cy2pnZ/2). `(0[7-9]|1[0-6])` matches either `0` followed with `7`, `8` or `9`, or `1` followed with a digit from `0` to `6`.